# Optimal way to insert highly-duplicated data into Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a set-like table: 
It consists of 2 primary columns and a dummy boolean non-primary column.
The table is replicated.
I write massively into this table and very often the entry already exists in the database.
Deletion of entries happens due to TTL and sometimes (not so often) due to DELETE queries.

What is the most performant way to write values into this table?

First option:

Just blindly write values.

Second option:

Check if the value already exists and write only if it is missing.

The second approach requires one more lookup before each write but saves database capacity because it doesn't propagate unnecessary writes to the other replicas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with option 1, and then tune the compaction strategies. Option 2 will add much more load to the cluster, as reads are always slower than writes, and if in your case inserts happen when previous data still in memtable, then they will be directly overwritten (so you may consider to tune memtable as well).

If you have high read/write ration, you can go with leveled compaction - it could be more optimized for this use case. If ratio isn't very high, leave the default compaction strategy.

But in any case you'll need to tune compaction:

1. decrease `gc_grace_period` to acceptable value, depending on how fast you can bring back nodes that are down;
2. change table options like `tombstone_compaction_interval` ([doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTable.html#compactSubprop__compactionSubpropertiesSTCS)), and maybe `unchecked_tombstone_compaction`;
3. You may also tune things like, `concurrent_compactors` & `compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec` to perform more aggressive compactions.

Comment: thanks for your response! But could you please clarify: as I understand reading has constant complexity and writing has O(number of replicas) complexity, right? So in general you can't say that writing is faster than reading. I'm talking of throughput here.

Comment: complexity of reading & writing depends on configured consistency level (CL). But for writing the complexity is (writing into memory + commitlog)*CL, while reading complexity is (N of SSTables to look inside)*CL, and lookup in SSTables is the file operation, with higher latencies.  Check the DSE Arch guide for more details on how read & write happens: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntTOC.html